# How to substitute value of var with sed

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a mapping of vars and I need to substitute the value of a specific vars dynamically in a bash script. My vars are like this:

```
array = {
    node1 = [
         {
           "apacheversion" = "1.0"
           "mysqlversion"  = "2.0"
         }
    ]
    node2 = [
         {
           "apacheversion" = "1.0"
           "mysqlversion"  = "2.0"
         }
    ]
}
```

So, I need to substitute with a 'sed' , the value of a apacheversion and mysqlversion..

> ```
> "apacheversion" = "new.value" "mysqlversion" = "new.value"
> ```

Is there any way to do only in a specifc node? For example only substitute in node1. If i'ts not possible I don't mind because it is a temporary file of vars.

Thanks!

Comment: Your input looks suspect,e.g., for node1 the square brackets don't close. For node2, the curly braces don't close.

Comment: Sorry, I just fix it.

Comment: What kind of data format is it? It looks similar to JSON, but not quite. If it is an established format, there may be dedicated parsers to manipulate it; note that `sed` and the like are very much discouraged for processing structured data.

Comment: It's a terraform var file.

Comment: Terraform native language --> https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/syntax/configuration.html

Comment: Terraform also supports configuration [in JSON format](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/syntax/json.html). Converting the configuration into JSON and then using `jq` would be the preferred way of programmatically editing the file.

Answer (score 2):

While it is generally preferable to use parsers, one way would be via `awk`. Select the block via regexes for `/start/,/end/` and then act on the block only:

```
 awk '/node1 = \[/,/\]/ {
        if ($0 ~ /apacheversion/) {gsub(/1.0/,"new.version")}
        if ($0 ~ /mysqlversion/) {gsub(/2.0/,"new.version")}
     } 1' file.terra
```

If you define e.g. `=` as field separator, you might as well be more general and replace any content of field 2 instead of doing `gsub` with a pattern match+substitution.

Now for using this in a script, get the variables from the environment:

```
#!/bin/bash
varAPA=2.0
varSQL=5.0
awk -v newAPA="$varAPA" -v newSQL="$varSQL" '/node1 = \[/,/\]/ {
        if ($0 ~ /apacheversion/) {gsub(/1.0/,newAPA)}
        if ($0 ~ /mysqlversion/) {gsub(/2.0/,newSQL)}
     } 1' file.terra
```